# Do you earn anything by finding all hidden chests?

Tags: super-mario-rpg

The treasure chest monster in Monstro Town will let you know how many hidden chests there are to find in the game. Do you get anything from him (or from anybody) by finding them all?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no reward for finding all the hidden chests other than what you find inside (plenty of flowers and frog coins) and a pleasant feeling of satisfaction. That disappointing moment from my childhood when I got that last box and discovered this little tidbit still haunts me.

Comment: and the best part is that one of the chests is only available during a very specific scene in the game so most player end up with one forever lost chest anyway.